# Restrict IFRAME and OBJECT embeds certain domains

Tags: 7, security

I would like to allow my users to embed certain IFRAME and OBJECT tags in nodes and comments. Is there a way to restrict them to certain domains, for example maps.google.com to allow embedding Google maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allowing users to input , and doing validation on *some* subtypes of that, is certainly possible, but far from easy.

It's easy to think, "I can do that with a regular expression!". Read [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) though, before you try, and save yourself a lot pain.

What you *can* do instead, is employ an XML parser and process the input from there, but that is far from trivial, and will require quite a bit of work.

What I recommend you *should* do instead, is create specific tags for what you want to allow. Something like [iframe:http://some.url.here], and then process these manually with an input filter. You would probably want to apply that filter in a text-format *after* you've run the regular "limited html" filter.

A filter is created by implementing [hook_filter_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.api.php/function/hook_filter_info/7), and in your [process callback](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.api.php/function/hook_filter_FILTER_process/7) you can do string substitution on the [iframe] tag, provided it references an approved domain.

Comment: Sounds very similar to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28300/how-to-filter-urls-for-embedded-img-tags for sure

Comment: It does indeed, the question itself is actually quite similar.

Comment: that's a good approach. I came across http://drupal.org/project/video_filter which does exactly that, I can probably reuse some code from it.